# Export images from sqlite to Excel file using xlsx writer

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, xlsxwriter

Unable to export image file to Excel from sqlite3 database using xlsx writer.

```
import sqlite3
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('ExportFile.xlsx')
conn=sqlite3.connect('demo.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UsersImage")
data = cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    zero = row[0]
    one = row[1]
    two = row[2]
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Test Sheet')
worksheet.write('A1', zero)
worksheet.insert_image('B1', one, {'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})
worksheet.insert_image('C1', row, {'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})
workbook.close()
```

Expect image files from sql Db to be displayed in excel sheet. Text values are displayed correctly.

ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path

**Table Syntax:**

```
CREATE TABLE `UsersImage` (
    `UserID`    integer,
    `UserImage` BLOB NOT NULL,
    `UserCar`   BLOB NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`UserID`)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XlsxWriter `insert_image()` API takes a path to an image file as input. I presume that isn't what the SQL query is returning.

XlsxWriter also supports images as an  in-memory byte stream in io.BytesIO format. See the `image_data` parameter in the  [`insert_image()` docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-insert-image):

```
worksheet.insert_image('B5', 'python.png', {'image_data': image_data})
```